# How NodeJS and Socket.IO serve socket.io.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I was learning NodeJS and Socket.IO via following code from a book(Learning Node). The example worked. But I want to know how the node is serving the **socket.io.js** file in the statment `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` Because there is no folder named socket.io in the project root and I don't have any code written to server static file. Is this done via Socket.IO module? Will it conflict if I use express to serve static files?

Client Side code

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>bi-directional communication</title>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8124');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        var html = '<p>' + data.news + '</p>';
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=html;
        socket.emit('echo', { back: data.news });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

server side code

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
, fs = require('fs')

var counter;
app.listen(8124);

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.writeHead(500);
            return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }
        counter = 1;
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { news: 'world' });
    socket.on('echo', function (data) {
        if (counter <= 50) {
            counter++;
            console.log(data.back);
            socket.emit('news', {news: data.back});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It's a virtual path. Basically, the server side library process the requests that begins with "/socket.io/" and outputs the resource. The actual file is somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some reading I got the explanation

In the server application, when the HTTP web server was created, it was passed to the
Socket.IO’s listen event:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
, io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
```

What happens is that Socket.IO intercepts requests sent to the web server and listens
for requests for:

```
/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

**Socket.IO does a clever bit of behind-the-scenes finagling that determines what’s re-
turned in the response. If the client supports WebSockets, the JavaScript file returned
is one that uses WebSockets to implement the client connection. If the client doesn’t
support WebSockets, but does support Forever iFrame (IE9), it returns that particular
JavaScript client code, and so on.**

Comment: The socket.io server-side code just hooks the route for `/socket.io` so it can serve anything it wants on any route that starts with that path.  That's how it sees the request for `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.  But, are you really sure that it serves something different based on client capabilities?  I was under the impression that it serves the same JS file no matter what and `socket.io.js` is what examines the client environment and decides what to do when it runs on the client.

Comment: You don't have to use this path for `socket.io.js`.  You could serve it from a CDN, but the advantage of letting your node server serve it in this way is that you are guaranteed to have a client and server-side socket.io library that are in sync and the same version because whenever you update the server-side socket.io (with NPM), you automatically get the client-side library too.